# Styles work differently based on if they're inside the html head tags or not?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I'm trying to make a fairly simple site which there's a div with some text inside, centered both horizontally and vertically on the page.

I wouldn't have thought this would be that difficult to do, but something quite weird's happening. Here's the source that **does work.** Let's call this source A.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jacob Garby</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="content">Test</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's the source that **doesn't work.** Let's call this source B.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jacob Garby</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="content">Test</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

They both use the same stylesheet, which is here:

```
* {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.wrap {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

div.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And the problem is that **the div.wrap is only vertically aligned when I link to the stylesheets *outside* of the html head tags.** This is the only difference between the source that works and the source that doesn't.

I know that you're meant to include source inside the head tags and that's why I think it's so strange that it *only* works when I do the opposite of this.

I would include a link to some exampls on jsfiddle or something, but the problem is how I'm including the stylesheets, which jsfiddle doesn't let me change.

I've tried this on all of the browsers I have (Opera, Firefox, and Chrome,) and the problem persists between them.

Is this some sort of HTML bug? Or am I making some obvious mistake?

---

Here are some screenshots.

Source A:
[image: Source A works]

Source B:
[image: Source B doesn't work]

I viewed the source in a web browser, and even when I link to the stylesheet outside the head, it seems to put it in there. So, in both examples, when actually viewed, the stylesheet is automatically being put in the head tags.

If my question isn't clear, it's basically this:

**Why is this strange behavior happening, and how can I fix it?**

Comment: But isn't the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag a different actual kind of tag to the opening `<html>` tag? I would've thought that part would be correct, since it was automatically generated by Atom.

Comment: @KyleSposato no, they're different with different purposes. Your comment is factually incorrect, I suggest you go and read about the DOCTYPE tag.

Comment: @KyleSposato er no, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype : "<!DOCTYPE> informs the browser which version of HTML (or XML) you used to write the document. **Doctype is a declaration, not a tag**; you can also refer to it as "document type declaration", or "DTD" for short." So, `<!Doctype>` tells the browser which version of HTML you're using. `<html>` is a HTML tag telling the browser that this is the start of the HTML document. Completely different purposes.

Comment: If it does "absolutely nothing different", I don't see any issue with writing code how my text editor suggests

Comment: @KyleSposato yes it does. A document without a `<html>` opening tag is technically invalid. A document without a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration could be interpreted by different rendering engines (probably depending on their age) as being in different versions of HTML, with potentially problematic results (e.g. ignoring HTML5 markup, or using different layout algorithms). You are failing to understand the difference between the two items of markup.

Comment: Valid DOCTYPE must be in the first line, I think what's probably happening here is that your first code isn't being treated as HTML 5 due to the lack of valid HTML5 DTD declaration. The browser probably treats it as older HTML, and it probably activates [quirks mode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Comment: @KyleS OK it's true that the html tag is potentially optional in some situations (although it's not recommended), but the original point was that you were saying that the code has "multiple opening html tags" and this is not correct. They are different with different purposes. DOCTYPE is not even technically a tag. You're implying they can be combined together, which is misleading, IMO. The `<html>` tag can be _ommitted_ (as long as DOCTYPE is present), but that's not the same as _merging_ the two. You might think I'm splitting hairs, but the devil is in the detail with a lot of programming.

Comment: I feel like this conversation should me moved to chat, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @KyleS Just using <!DOCTYPE html>` and then not including `<html>` isn't making them "combined together", it's quite simply just omitting `<html>`. I'm making the point that your choice of language is misleading. One is a declaration, the other is a HTML tag. They're different types of thing, so logically they can't be "combined" or "separated". Apologies if my tone came across hostile, it wasn't the intention, I just sought to clarify the difference between the two items. If they really could be combined, there'd be no point having the two separate at all. That's my final word on it.

Comment: You're both commenting equally frequently - equally annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not strange but your HTML is invalid by doing it that way in A.

[Browsers are required to do the best they can with invalid markup.](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Validating_your_HTML#Different_browsers_interpret_invalid_HTML_differently) The problem with that, of course, is that you are relying on the browser to guess correctly at your intentions so don't write invalid markup.

Comment: So you're saying it would be better to keep the link tags inside the head?

Comment: @JacobGarby Not only is it better, it's required! https://developers.whatwg.org/semantics.html#the-link-element "If the rel attribute is used, the element is restricted to the head element."

Comment: Okay - but then the div isn't vertically centered.

Comment: That's a different issue with your CSS.